# Iterate through a for loop with the help of react and read out the data record

Tags: reactjs

I am using React and a for loop to query a data record of an object.
The object (current user) has different attributes. Including 17 true / false values. The only difference in name is the number:
currentUser.F56_FB_Urlaub_KW22, currentUser.F56_FB_Urlaub_KW23, currentUser.F56_FB_Urlaub_KW24, ...

I would now like to generate these numbers using the for loop.
How can I achieve this ?
I get a NaN error with my code:

```
function baueKWs(aktuellerUser) {

for (var i = 22; i <= 39; i++) {

  const element = (

    <FormControlLabel

      control={

        <Checkbox

          checked={aktuellerUser.F56_FB_Urlaub_KW + i}

          id={`KW` + i}

          onChange={(e) => aendereKW(e)}

          name={`KW` + i}

        />

      }

      label={`KW` + i}

    />

  );

  items.push(element);

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aktuellerUser.F56_FB_Urlaub_KW + i` returns `NaN` since `aktuellerUser.F56_FB_Urlaub_KW` is `undefined` and `undefined + i` is `NaN`. You can use

```
`F56_FB_Urlaub_KW${i}`
```

to construct the key.

```
<Checkbox
  checked={aktuellerUser[`F56_FB_Urlaub_KW${i}`]}
  id={`KW${i}`}
  onChange={aendereKW}
  name={`KW${i}`}
/>
```

Btw, the `baueKWs` function is missing a `return` statement. You can simplify your code by creating a range of numbers from 22 to 39 and using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the checkboxes.

```
const range = (start, end) =>
  Array.from({ length: end - start + 1 }, (_, i) => start + i)

const baueKWs = (aktuellerUser) =>
  range(22, 39).map((i) => (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={aktuellerUser[`F56_FB_Urlaub_KW${i}`]}
          id={`KW${i}`}
          onChange={aendereKW}
          name={`KW${i}`}
        />
      }
      label={`KW${i}`}
    />
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answer has pointed out your problem. Below is another way to write your function.

```
function baueKWs(aktuellerUser) {
  const filteredProperties = Object.keys(aktuellerUser).filter(item => typeof aktuellerUser[item] === "boolean")  
 // Just in case your object has other properties with different types

  const items = filteredProperties.map((item, i) => { 
     const identifier = "KW" + i + 22; 
     return (<FormControlLabel
         control={
           <Checkbox
            checked={aktuellerUser[item]}
            id={identifier}
            onChange={(e) => aendereKW(e)}
            name={identifier}
           />}
        label={identifier}
        />)
     })
 }
```